# How apt know if an obsolete package is replaced by another one?

Tags: apt, packaging

During the installation of `mysql-server` on raspbian buster, `apt` say that `mysql-server` isn't available and suggest `mariadb-server-10.0` as replacement.

How `apt` know if a package is replaced with another one? In other word where this information should be set in during the package creation?

```
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-10.0

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `apt show mariadb-server-10.3` (I have newer version), you will see this:

```
Package: mariadb-server-10.3
Version: 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1
Priority: optional
Section: database
Source: mariadb-10.3
Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 66,6 MB
Provides: virtual-mysql-server
Pre-Depends: adduser (>= 3.40), debconf, mariadb-common (>= 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1)
Depends: galera-3 (>= 25.3), gawk, iproute2, libdbi-perl, lsb-base (>= 3.0-10), lsof, mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1), mariadb-server-core-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1), passwd, perl (>= 5.6), psmisc, rsync, socat, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.28), libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.6), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0)
Recommends: libhtml-template-perl
Suggests: mailx, mariadb-test, netcat-openbsd, tinyca
Conflicts: mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0, mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.1, mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5, mysql-server-core-5.5, mysql-server-core-5.6, mysql-server-core-5.7, virtual-mysql-server
Breaks: cqrlog (<< 1.9.0-5~), mariadb-galera-server, mariadb-galera-server-10.0, mariadb-galera-server-5.5, mariadb-server-10.0, mariadb-server-10.1, mariadb-server-10.2, mariadb-server-5.5, mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0, mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.1, mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5, mysql-client-5.5, mysql-server-5.5, mysql-server-5.6, mysql-server-5.7
Replaces: mariadb-galera-server, mariadb-galera-server-10.0, mariadb-galera-server-5.5, mariadb-server-10.0, mariadb-server-10.1, mariadb-server-10.2, mariadb-server-5.5, mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0, mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.1, mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5, mysql-client-5.5, mysql-server-5.5, mysql-server-5.6, mysql-server-5.7, virtual-mysql-server
Homepage: https://mariadb.org/
Download-Size: 4 202 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
Description: MariaDB database server binaries
MariaDB is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
language in the world. The main goals of MariaDB are speed, robustness and
ease of use.
.
This package includes the server binaries.
```

The line starting with `Replaces:` lists [the packages which this one can replace](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#overwriting-files-and-replacing-packages-replaces).